# why STL separates data structures and algorithms

Tags: c++, stl

(i'm sorry.im not good in english.im iranian)
we know that the purpose of oop is merging data structures and algorithms to provide a single entity.so the STL separates them.why STL didn't write their **own** methods as member functions??

Comment: Because N algorithms + M data structures is less code to write than N algorithms * M data structures.

Comment: Why not write an algo that anyone can use instead of making you write your own since there is not a generic function.

Comment: If you make an algorithm a member function you can't re-use it for other objects that behave in a similar way.

Comment: The STL was never OOP. Because Stepanov is smart.

Comment: It is not really data structures (in general) and algorithms that are separated (most `std` structures do contain some methods!). For the most part, it is _container types_ and algorithms that are separated.

Answer (score 4):

Consider implementing what you're suggesting - every data structure would have to re-implement every algorithm:

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
    auto for_each(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    auto partition(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    auto sort(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
};

template <typename T>
class list
{
    auto for_each(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    auto partition(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    auto sort(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
};

template <typename TK, typename TV>
class map
{
    auto for_each(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    auto partition(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    auto sort(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
};
```

As you can see, there is **severe code duplication**. Also, this approach is **unmaintainable**, as adding a new algorithm will require the implementation of every container to be changed.

---

If [UFCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax) is going to be accepted into the standard alongside [ranges](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), then you will be able to call algorithms on standard containers **as if** they were member functions:

```
std::vector<int> v{/* ... */};
v.sort(); // Actually calls `std::sort(v)` thanks to UFCS.
```